# htaccess: is "Allow from 127.0.0.1" safe

Tags: .htaccess, ip-address, whitelist

I have a website where I keep a dev copy on my local computer, and a live copy on my webhost.

I want to ip-whitelist a particular subdirectory to allow only me to access it. However, if I am working on my local copy via my home network, my ip is 127.0.0.1, whereas when I am working on the live site via the internet my ip address is 184.255.27.13.

So I added both ip's to my .htaccess (identical copy on local server and webhost server):

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 184.255.27.13
```

Is there any danger to upload the htaccess to the webserver with that generic 127.0.0.1 included?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any danger to upload the htaccess to the webserver with that generic 127.0.0.1 included?

No, since if someone malicious is connecting to your webhosted server from `127.0.0.1`, they've already got access to the server itself.

Comment: Jon, that makes sense ... I would like for a few others to verify this before I CHECK it as the answer. But it seems like sensible logic to me ...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not, but there could be a security risk, depending on your server configuration.

If you are running beside apache, nginx or stunnel or haproxy or similar software that act as a reverse proxy, and configure it as reverse proxy for the apache server, the apache server could see all incomming connections coming from 127.0.0.1.

But that is not going to happen to a basic LAMP configuration.